# I need to write Junit Test cases for Jersey Rest web service ..Please help me or post a sample code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest, junit, jersey

This is the code for which I am looking to write Junit test cases--

```
@GET 

@Path("/get")

@Produces("application/json")

public User getUser() 
{

    User user= new com.rest.rahul.User();

    user.setEmpid("12");
    user.setEmail("DJ@gmail.com");
    user.setName("DJ");
    return user;

}
```

Comment: Which part is not working?

Comment: @simon...I am new to Junit test cases for jersey rest webservice..It's not about abt which part is not working..I need to write Junit test cases for rest web service without running the server....

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to unit test? I wouldn't bother with unit testing simply setters. But if you want to test the JSON output, you're actually looking for something like an an integration test. A test that bootstraps your application, sets up the webservice and then calls the `getUser` method.
Take a look at https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/05/writing-lightweight-rest-integration-tests-with-the-jersey-test-framework/

Answer (score 1):

Testing a web service with JUnit involves starting up the web service inside the test environment, performing the request, validating the response and then shutting it down.

You can use Jersey's REST Client to perform a request on a server that comes up when the test runs. Get the response and Assert your required conditions on the response object.

More on Jersey's client here:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/